# Disabling autocomplete in Firefox 2

Tags: html, autocomplete, firefox2

The ff. works in Firefox 3 but not in Firefox 2.  Anyone know why and if there is a work-around?

```
<input name="pin" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=289077.  Seems that setting this attrib to off disables the **saving** of the data but not the **retrieval**.  In my case, the data had already been saved before I introduced the attribute so it was still displayed.